# Button property not updating in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have an array of custom buttons `capsuleButtons` in *ViewModel.swift* file which are displayed using ForEach in C*ontentView*. Each button is connected to an external property named `isActive` to display its current state, buttons created using the ForEach are not updating where as if created without ForEach (with title `ContentView btn`), is updating as expected. What am I missing here?

***ContentView***

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(vm.capsuleButtons, id: \.self) { button in
                HStack {
                    button
                }
            }
            CapsuleButton(title: "ContentView btn", action: { vm.isActive.toggle() } , active: vm.isActive)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct CapsuleButton: View, Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: CapsuleButton, rhs: CapsuleButton) -> Bool {
        lhs.title == rhs.title && lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
            hasher.combine(title)
            hasher.combine(id)
        }
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    let action: () -> Void
    var active = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(title, action: action)
            .background( active ? Color.pink : Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(active ? Color.white : Color.black)
    }
}
```

***ViewModel.swift***

```
import Foundation
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isActive = false
    var capsuleButtons = [CapsuleButton]()
    init() {
        self.isActive = false
        self.capsuleButtons = [CapsuleButton(title: "Button 1", action: {self.isActive.toggle()}, active: isActive),
                               CapsuleButton(title: "Button 2", action: {self.isActive.toggle()}, active: isActive)]

    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend removing the view model object and learning the view struct

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a few things that are or are close to breaking the SwiftUI diffing system.

First, you're telling the system an untruth by trying to make your `View` conform to `Hashable` and `Equatable` and then saying that the `title` and `id` are the only properties that matter, where you *definitely* also want `active` to be part of it.

Secondly, in general, you shouldn't be storing references to `View`s -- especially with IDs that get created on `init` -- that's a SwiftUI anti pattern. Instead, render a `View` hierarchy based on your *model*.

Finally, in your `action`s, you are *always* setting `self.isActive` -- I assume that you actually wanted to set the `Button`'s active state, but you were always setting it on the `ViewModel`'s state.

Something like this (not the only solution) would work instead:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(vm.capsuleButtons) { button in
                HStack {
                    CapsuleButton(model: button) {
                        vm.action(forID: button.id)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CapsuleButtonModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var active: Bool
}

struct CapsuleButton: View {
    var model: CapsuleButtonModel
    let action: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        Button(model.title, action: action)
            .background(model.active ? Color.pink : Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(model.active ? Color.white : Color.black)
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isActive = false
    @Published var capsuleButtons = [CapsuleButtonModel]()
    init() {
        self.isActive = false
        self.capsuleButtons = [CapsuleButtonModel(title: "Button 1", active: isActive),
                               CapsuleButtonModel(title: "Button 2", active: isActive)]

    }
    
    func action(forID: UUID) {
        self.capsuleButtons = self.capsuleButtons.map { btn in
            if btn.id == forID {
                var copy = btn
                copy.active.toggle()
                return copy
            } else {
                return btn
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also get rid of the `action(for)` function and replace it with a `Binding` (in particular, read about SwiftUI element binding syntax: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/bindable-swiftui-list-elements/). Then it turns into something even more simple:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach($vm.capsuleButtons) { $button in
                HStack {
                    CapsuleButton(model: $button)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CapsuleButtonModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var active: Bool
}

struct CapsuleButton: View {
    @Binding var model: CapsuleButtonModel
    var body: some View {
        Button(model.title, action: {
            model.active.toggle()
        })
            .background(model.active ? Color.pink : Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(model.active ? Color.white : Color.black)
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isActive = false
    @Published var capsuleButtons = [CapsuleButtonModel]()
    init() {
        self.isActive = false
        self.capsuleButtons = [CapsuleButtonModel(title: "Button 1", active: isActive),
                               CapsuleButtonModel(title: "Button 2", active: isActive)]

    }
}
```